# Php syntax error syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' str_replace, PSR-0 Autoloader

Tags: php, syntax, str-replace, autoloader, psr-0

I'm dabbling w/ a 'lightweight' PSR-0 AutoLoader for a WordPress Plugin, 
it runs fine on my local dev server, but when i push it up to one of WPEngine's staging servers, i get this:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /nas/wp/www/staging/ahsodesigns/wp-content/plugins/AhSoFunctionality/start.php on line 30

here's the AutoLoader,

```
// lightweight psr-0 autoloader
spl_autoload_register(function ($classname) {
    // make sure we're only loading classes from our directory,
    if (preg_match('/AhSo/',$classname)) {
        $classname = ltrim($classname, "\\");
        preg_match('/^(.+)?([^\\\\]+)$/U', $classname, $match);
        $classname = str_replace("\\", "/", $match[1])
            . str_replace(["\\", "_"], "/", $match[2])
            . ".php";
        include_once $classname;
    }
});
```

the issue is on this line,

```
$classname = str_replace("\\", "/", $match[1])
            . str_replace(["\\", "_"], "/", $match[2])
            . ".php";
```

apparently it doesn't like the brackets...
i've tried a few quick things, like moving the concatenation all to one line. no luck, 
i'm guessing it's probably some kind of php.ini thing, or maybe i've got a rogue line ending character in their that WPEngine's php config doesn't like.
the file was built in phpStorm w/ Unix line separators '\n'.
i wish i had more time to mess with it, but you know how that goes.
thanks again stack.
best. resource. ever.

Comment: Try `array(...)` instead of `[...]`? (The [shortened array syntax](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) isn't available until [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/releases/5_4_0.php).)

Comment: does not show any research effort? that's not at all subjective. sadly i maxed out my 'research effort time' within the scope of our daily workflow. so i went to stack. haters hate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using php 5.4 array notation, it's not supported in lower PHP versions.
Change it to

```
$classname = str_replace("\\", "/", $match[1])
        . str_replace(array("\\", "_"), "/", $match[2])
        . ".php";
```

Comment: as the boss would say: "BAM"! that did it. time to brush up on my php version inconsistencies. tyty Aurimas Ličkus!